# Include search in Microsoft graph query C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How do I run the query

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:room"&$filter=endsWith(mail,'xxxx.com')&$select=id,displayName,mail](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search=%22displayName:room%22&$filter=endsWith(mail,%27xxxx.com%27)&$select=id,displayName,mail)

in C#?

this is what I have now:

```
 return await _graphServiceClient
                 .Users.Request()                                
                 .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
   .             .Filter($"(endsWith(mail, 'xxxx.com'))&$count=true")
                 .Select("id,displayName,mail")
                 .Top(999)
                 .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code pls:

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
    new QueryOption("$search", "\"displayName:tiny\"")
};
var res = await graphClient
    .Users.Request(queryOptions)
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
    .Filter("endswith(mail,'contoso.com')")
    .OrderBy("userPrincipalName")
    .Select("id,displayName,mail")
    .Top(999)
    .GetAsync();
```

When we follow the official [code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-5), we should use `.Search()` but it will meet exception:

[image]

Then let's see [github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-devx-api/issues/705) here, and we can set search parameter into query option.